# Detecting and/or changing the encoding of a file in php

Tags: php, encoding, fgets

I have the following php code. It reads out a file that the client uploads (in a Drupal site).

```
$fp = fopen($fileUri, 'r');
$buffer = 4096;
while(($line = fgets($fp, $buffer)) ){
    if (preg_match("/last update/", $line)) {
       // do something here...
    }
}
```

However, the "do something here" is never reached when the user uploads a file with UCS-2LE encoding. With ANSI or UTF-8, everything works fine.

I've tried converting the encoding with `mb_convert_encoding` and/or detecting it with `mb_detect_encoding`. I've also tried `iconv`. Nothing seems to work.

So what is the best way of ensuring my `preg_match` works, when I don't know what encoding the client's file will be?

**UPDATE**

My form has `accept-charset=UTF-8` and these are my request headers:

[image: request headers]

Comment: detecting encoding is inherently risky. you can't authoritatively say a file is encoding X based on looking through it. e.g. it's impossible to tell UTF-8 from ASCII if the file never users any chars with values > 127. At best you can say a file ISN'T a particular encoding because something inside the file violates the encoding rules.

Comment: Does mb_detect_encoding return FALSE?

Comment: Could you check if there is a request header `Content-Type` that sets the `charset` on the **upload** that could indicate the correct encoding? If not, try to force it on the **upload** form `<form accept-charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: Apparently, the form already has `accept-charset=UTF-8` (it's a Drupal module I'm making). I updated my question with info on the request headers.

Comment: @PaoloNiccolòGiubelli most lines return 'ASCII', some 'UTF-8'.

Comment: You probably should read the entire file, put every line into a single string and use mb_detect_encoding on the entire string.

Comment: @PaoloNiccolòGiubelli loading the entire file into a string and detecting the encoding gives me an empty string as result. I'm thinking about changing the workflow and having the user just paste the text into a textarea. Unless you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Encoding is a messy thing. A text area can be a quick fix, but you could also check the encoding of the file and reject it if it doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: @PaoloNiccolòGiubelli yes, but that wouldn't be good UX, in my opinion. I've talked with the end-user and apparently he's copy-pasting it from another file in the first place (from Excel to txt file). So it even cuts out an extra step if he only needs to paste it in my site. Not sure what the answer to this question is now though...